# How is the topology on $\ell^2$ and $\ell^p$ spaces called?

Tags: general-topology, metric-spaces, hilbert-spaces, lp-spaces, normed-spaces

I am looking for a specific name for the topology induced by metric on $\ell^2$. This space has its "standard" topology generated by $\sqrt{\sum_{i=1}^{\infty}(x_i-y_i)^2}$. With such topology, the space can be called Hilbert space.

What do we usually call this topology? And is it similar topology as on $\ell^p$ spaces?

Also, the vector space $\mathbb{R^{\infty}}$ is endowed with the Tychonoff product topology and $\ell^2$ should be a subset of this space. Does it mean that $\ell^2$ "inherits" the Tychonoff product topology or it is at least possible to give to $\ell^2$, even though it is not the standard choice?

Comment: The usual term is the norm topology. And yes, you could give an $\ell^p$ space the subspace topology induced by the product topology.

Comment: I usually call them "$\ell^2$ topology" and "$\ell^p$ topology".